# Select2 Post Text instead of value

Tags: html, ajax, model-view-controller, jquery-select2

When i write some letters in my input select2 goes in controller finds filtered matches and gives back on view the text i need . when i select the texts and post all the tags Id comes not the text. i want Text to be posted not id any suggesdtions ? 
I send all the inputs in tags[] in controller . If the value doesnt exist in base its posted as text but if it is found it is posted as id

HTML

```
 <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control"  id="tags" style="width: 400px;"  value="tags" name="tags[]"></select>


 <script>
$("#tags").select2(
    {
        allowClear: true,
        tags: true,
        tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],

        ajax: {
            url: "/Entry/ReadSelect2DataMulti",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term,
                    page: params.page || 1
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {
                params.page = params.page || 1;
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            },
            cache: true,
            error: function (xhr, textStarus, error) {
            }
        },
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        placeholder: "აირჩიეთ პოზიცია",
        templateResult: function (state) {
            var result = '<div class="pos-template">' + '<span title=""><b>' + state.text + '</b></span>';
            if (state.content != null && state.content != '') {

                var tags = state.content.split(",");
                for (i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
                    result = result + '<span class="pos-tag">' + tags[i] + '</span>';
                }
            }
            result = result + '</div></div>';

            return $(result);
        },
        id: function (object) {
            return object.text;
        },
        language: {
            noResults: function () {
            },
            inputTooShort: function () {
                return "შეავსეთ მინიმიმ 2 სიმბოლო";
            },
            loadingMore: function () {
                return 'იტვირთება...';
            },
            searching: function () {
                return 'იფილტრება...';
            }
        },
    }
);
//$('#tags').select2('val');
```